# What's the fastest way to upload an image to a webserver?

Tags: image, upload

I am building an application which will allow users to upload images. Mostly, it will work with mobile browsers with slow internet connections. I was wondering if there are best practices for this. Does doing some encryption and than doing the transfer and decoding on server is a trick to try ? OR something else?

Answer (score 0):

You would want something preferably with resumable uploads. Since your connections is slow you'd need something that can be resumed where you left off. A library i've come across over the many years is Nginx upload module:

http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html

**According to the site:**
The module parses request body storing all files being uploaded to a directory specified by upload_store directive. The files are then being stripped from body and altered request is then passed to a location specified by upload_pass directive, thus allowing arbitrary handling of uploaded files. Each of file fields are being replaced by a set of fields specified by upload_set_form_field directive. The content of each uploaded file then could be read from a file specified by $upload_tmp_path variable or the file could be simply moved to ultimate destination. Removal of output files is controlled by directive upload_cleanup. If a request has a method other than POST, the module returns error 405 (Method not allowed). Requests with such methods could be processed in alternative location via error_page directive.

Comment: I followed a lot of QnA and they all say the upload module doesn't support new nginx releases. Does nginx-upload-module support nginx new releases 1.8.x +? If not, then what is the other solution?